# How to change the datasource type on a crystal reports file

Tags: crystal-reports

Is it possible to change the datasource type on a crystal reports file without having to rebuild the entire report?

I know that I can go to Database / Set Datasource Location and change some datasource definitions like servername, login, password, but what do I have to do to change from an ODBC (RDO) datasource type to OLEDB?

I already tried adding a new datasource to the report and add the required tables from that datasource but when doing so I have to rename them because Crystal Reports doesn't seems to be able to handle tables with the same name but different datasources...

Comment: You can trying creating a new report using the new datasource. Then copy & paste the Crystal Report objects to the new report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about through the designer or programmatically?

Designer: go to "Set Datasource Location" dialog, create the oledb connection in the lower pane, select an existing table in the top pane, select the matching oledb table, hit the "update" button. Repeat for each table.

Programmatically: not sure but it's probably a pain. :)

Comment: already tried to do that as was in the original post... i'm not only tring to change the datasource location but also datasource type

Comment: That is how you change the connection type. I thought your post was talking about changing the values of the existing connection.